# React: error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null

I was trying to solve this error by myself with the help of previous posts but unsuccessful.
I'm trying to take the "state.ingredients" property(I think), I'm talking about the "sugar" "coffee" "water" etc
I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> This is the CoffeeBuilder.js the important part of the code:

```
const ingPrices = {
    sugar: 0,
    coffee: 0.2,
    water: 0,
    milk: 0.2,
};

class CoffeeBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ingredients: {
                sugar: 0,
                coffee: 0,
                water: 0,
                milk: 0,
            },
            totalPrice: 0,
            purchasing: false,
        };
    }

    addIngHandler = (type) => {
        const newCount = this.state.ingredients[type] + 1;
        console.log("clicked");
        const updatedIng = { ...this.state.ingredients };
        updatedIng[type] = newCount;

        const ING_PRICE = ingPrices[type];
        const oldPrice = this.state.totalPrice;
        this.setState({
            totalPrice: oldPrice + ING_PRICE,
            ingredients: newCount,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CoffeeSlider />
                <CoffeeControls addIng={this.addIngHandler} removeIng={this.removeIngHandler} />
                <OrderSummary ingredients={this.state.ingredients} price={this.state.totalPrice} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CoffeeBuilder;
```

This is the OrderSummary.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./OrderSummary.css";

const OrderSummary = (props) => {
    return Object.keys(props.ingredients).map((igKey) => {
        console.log(igKey);
        return (
            <div>
                <li key={igKey}>
                    <span style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{igKey}</span>:
                    {props.ingredients[igKey]}
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    });
};

export default OrderSummary;
```

the console.log fetches the data fine, but when I'm trying to return it in a span as a list, it goes wrong.

Comment: Can you also share full code of  `<OrderSummary />`?

Comment: I've added <OrderSummary /> code and the important parts of the <CoffeeBuilder /> code
I hope it helps, Thank you.

Comment: Do you currently have the line `<OrderSummary ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />` below `export default CoffeeBuilder`?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Never mind! Seems you removed that line already :) Are you still running into the problem?

Comment: oh yes... I did some tests in console.log, came out very weird. editing it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. In order to help you in this case, you might have to provide codesanbox link for replicating or we can't help?

Comment: I copied all the important files into code sandbox and it worked fine. 
This seems like a long shot I will start again with a github link to my code so it will be clearer. Thanks for the help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try CoffeBuilder component like this, your code has few issues such as state is not being declared in constructor, no render function.

Below is the codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mountain-235yk?file=/src/App.js

```js
class CoffeeBuilder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ingredients: {
        sugar: 0,
        coffee: 0,
        water: 0,
        milk: 0,
      },
      totalPrice: 0,
      purchasing: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( < OrderSummary ingredients = {
        this.state.ingredients
      }
      />);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried that but it's still the same.

And why is it important to add the constructor and super(props)? So I can know in the future :)

Comment: @C0deN3rd Please go through the codesandbox link in the answer, you may get an idea. . Constructor gets called before the component is mounted and as per react documentaion, constructors have one of the  purposes is Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.

Comment: OK, I will check now.

Comment: If this works for you , then please mark this as answer. Others may have similar questions which will help them.

Comment: That's weird.. it still doesn't work... I've added render() and constructor and still nothing..

Got any suggestions to what it may be?

Comment: Unless I see your code it's difficult to say any soltion for that.

Comment: I don't know what I can add to help with the solution, so weird...

Comment: Have put as much as example in the codesandbox link.Unless I see your code its difficult.